# Human readable display of a list of things

Tags: rust

Just for fun, I created this small function that prints an iterator in a String:

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Write};

fn enumerate<T: Display, I: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(it: I) -> String {
    let mut it = it.into_iter().peekable();
    let mut result = String::new();

    if let Some(first) = it.next() {
        write!(result, "{}", first).unwrap();
        if it.peek().is_some() {
            while let Some(item) = it.next() {
                match it.peek() {
                    Some(_) => write!(result, ", {}", item),
                    None => write!(result, " and {}", item),
                }.unwrap();
            }
        }
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(enumerate(Vec::<i32>::new()), "");
    assert_eq!(enumerate(vec![1]), "1");
    assert_eq!(enumerate(vec![1, 2]), "1 and 2");
    assert_eq!(enumerate(vec![1, 2, 3]), "1, 2 and 3");
    assert_eq!(enumerate(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]), "1, 2, 3 and 4");
}
```

But I am not really satisfied with it. It is not really readable, and I am switching between `next` and `peek` in nested blocks. I wonder if this is possible to write the function in a more functional manner?

Answer (score 4):

1. It's often more readable to write trait bounds (e.g. `T: Display`) in a `where` clause rather than directly next to the declaration. Also, there are some types of bounds that cannot be written with the angle brackets and must instead be written in a `where` clause (there are examples below). When you have a `where` clause, put all the bounds here; don't put bounds in both places, because then it's easy for someone reading the code to miss the bounds in the angle brackets.
2. You don't need the `T` type parameter on your function; you can write the bound `I::Item: Display` to get the same effect.
3. The `if it.peek().is_some()` is unnecessary; if that expression returns `false`, the program wouldn't enter the `while let` loop anyway, and that loop is the only statement in the `if`.
4. By using [`DoubleEndedIterator::next_back`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html#tymethod.next_back), we can extract the last item from the iterator. This lets us remove the peeks to determine whether you should use a comma or "and" as the separator. However, this restricts the types of iterators that the function accepts, because the iterator must now implement `DoubleEndedIterator`. In order to write this requirement, we *must* write the bound `I::IntoIter: DoubleEndedIterator` in a `where` clause; we can't write this within the angle brackets.

```
fn enumerate<I>(it: I) -> String
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Display,
    I::IntoIter: DoubleEndedIterator,
{
    let mut it = it.into_iter();
    let mut result = String::new();

    if let Some(first) = it.next() {
        write!(result, "{}", first).unwrap();

        if let Some(last) = it.next_back() {
            while let Some(item) = it.next() {
                write!(result, ", {}", item).unwrap();
            }

            write!(result, " and {}", last).unwrap();
        }
    }

    result
}
```

> I wonder if this is possible to write the function in a more functional manner?

Building upon the code above, we can replace the `while let` loop with a [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold).

```
fn enumerate<I>(it: I) -> String
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Display,
    I::IntoIter: DoubleEndedIterator,
{
    let mut it = it.into_iter();
    let mut result = String::new();

    if let Some(first) = it.next() {
        write!(result, "{}", first).unwrap();

        if let Some(last) = it.next_back() {
            result = it.fold(result, |mut result, item| {
                write!(result, ", {}", item).unwrap();
                result
            });

            write!(result, " and {}", last).unwrap();
        }
    }

    result
}
```

`write!` doesn't "feel" functional, though, because it mutates its operand rather than returning a new value. Therefore, in this case, I don't think the version with `fold` is really more readable than the version with `while let`.

By using [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools), a third-party crate published on [crates.io](https://crates.io/), we can simplify the code a bit and give it a more functional feel by using its [`join`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.6/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join) adapter. [Its implementation](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.6/src/itertools/lib.rs.html#1411-1428) is more or less what we were doing before.

```
extern crate itertools;

use std::fmt::{Display, Write};
use std::iter;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn enumerate<I>(it: I) -> String
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Display,
    I::IntoIter: DoubleEndedIterator,
{
    let mut it = it.into_iter();

    if let Some(first) = it.next() {
        if let Some(last) = it.next_back() {
            let mut result = iter::once(first)
                .chain(it)
                .join(", ");

            write!(result, " and {}", last).unwrap();
            result
        } else {
            format!("{}", first)
        }
    } else {
        String::new()
    }
}
```